# Azure functions host run configuration - run all functions

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

I am new to .NET and Azure.
I have an Azure functions app that I run from my Rider IDE locally. I attach a screenshot of my run configuration.
It runs successfully but requires me to specify which "functions to run" (the red bar from the screenshot). If I do not specify any function it runs none. What I want is it to run all functions because I cannot provide all of them there (its a huge list that changes).
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Functions are pieces of code that execute when a certain trigger occurs. This can be an HTTP request, a message on a queue, a blob being created in a specific container or a timer going off based on a cron expression.
This means that when the Functions runtime is running, *all Functions are ready to go as soon as their trigger occurs*.

To trigger the execution of a Function for testing purposes there are a couple of options. You can either make the trigger occur by calling the URL, adding a message on a queue, creating a blob in a container or have your timer trigger configured to [RunOnStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#configuration) (please be advised this is **not** recommended to go in production).

Another option would be to use the admin URL available.

> In some contexts, you may need to run "on-demand" an Azure Function that is indirectly triggered. Examples of indirect triggers include functions on a schedule or functions that run as the result of another resource's action.

and

> To run a non HTTP-triggered function, you need a way to send a request to Azure to run the function. The URL used to make this request takes a specific form.
>
> [image: Azure Functions admin URL]

When calling the admin URL in Azure, you need to specify the Function's master key, but

> When running locally, the function's master key is not required. You can directly call the function omitting the `x-functions-key` header.

Source: [Manually run a non HTTP-triggered function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http)

**EDIT:**
If you manually start the functions by running `func start` in the project directory, all Functions will be started. To do so, make sure you have the Azure Functions Core Tools installed.

> Azure Functions Core Tools lets you develop and test your functions on your local computer from the command prompt or terminal. Your local functions can connect to live Azure services, and you can debug your functions on your local computer using the full Functions runtime. You can even deploy a function app to your Azure subscription.

More info: [Work with Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local)

Especially interesting: the chapter [Run functions locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#start).

> To run a Functions project, you run the Functions host from the root directory of your project. The host enables triggers for all functions in the project. The start command varies depending on your project language.

**EDIT 2:**
As added as a comment below: when running Azure Functions from a different IDE than Visual Studio, like JetBrains' Rider, **please make sure the working directory is set to the root of the Functions project**.

Comment: Hi @rickvdbosch , thanks for the info. My functions are triggered by HTTP calls. In the runtime config in the section "functions to run" if I specify the particular function as name, then I can call it via HTTP calls, otherwise the HTTP call returns 404, NOT FOUND. Example, if I add function "MyFunc" when my app starts it writes Api_MyFunc_v1: [POST] http://localhost:7071/api/Test and I can successfully POST at this URL

Comment: @ValentinMezev Have a look at the updated answer

Comment: Amazing. I set your comment as answer. While reading it I understood the reason of my problems. Can I ask you to edit it and just add a bolded Note people to make sure their working directory is correctly specified in their IDE run config to point to the root of the App (I also added an answer below to summarize the solution)

Comment: That was it! Working directory was set to `bin/Debug/net6.0`, not the root folder. Fixed this and finally all functions are up and running.